# How can I preload without soft deleted using Repo

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

Using `Elixir`, `Ecto.Repo`, `Postgres`.

I have an association between `User` and `Company` through a join table `UserRelations`. I am building a dynamic query in a function for the user with the company.

In the company schema I use soft delete, so in the preload, I want to exclude them, can I use with opts in the preload?

```
dynamic_query
|> Repo.all
|> Repo.preload(include_deleted: false)
```

Comment: Did you try https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-queries?

Answer (score 1):

You might explicitly query `:deleted_at` field:

```rb
preload_query =
  from c in Company, where: fragment("deleted_at IS NULL")

dynamic_query
|> Repo.all()
|> Repo.preload(preload: [company: ^preload_query])
```

[*Based on this gist*](https://gist.github.com/ahmadshah/83a695ac66d98a833d6d576815e6931d).

Comment: are you sure this is applied at preload? You are applying the query to the `Repo.all()` meaning that he will get only the users that are not soft deleted and it will preload all the companies including even the ones that are soft deleted. The correct way would be to use the query inside of the `Repo.preload()` call.

Comment: @Daniel oh, indeed. I will update the answer. Thanks!